# R studio using time-series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have CVS file with three columns

```
EX : name | number | boolean 
     joan   4        true   etc...
```

I want to convert CSV file to time-series plot, and tried those commands in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv(".../.../.../outpots/names.csv")
ggplot(data, aes(name, number)) + geom_line()
```

but I see graph without the plot inside

thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi Ali - welcome to SO - help us help you - you should provide some more information on your data and what you want to show. Maybe the results of `dput(data)` or if the dataframe is big `dput(data[1:12,])`?

Comment: Please review [mcve].  This time I have provided some test input in reproducible form in my answer but please provide such next time you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` field is a factor rather than a numeric field but we can use it on a line plot anyways by adding `group=1` to the `aes()` specification.  This would also work if `name` were a character field.

```
library(ggplot2) 
DF <- data.frame(name = letters, number = 1:26)  # test input

ggplot(DF, aes(name, number, group = 1)) + geom_line()
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]